# Unwanted nodes and edges while plotting nebula knowledge graph using pyvis

Tags: information-retrieval, knowledge-graph, llama-index, nebula-graph, pyvis

**Context:**

We created a graph index using `llama-index` on our own custom documents. Triplets were created and stored in the Nebula graph DB.

We used the following snippet (taken from `llama-index` official documentation) to plot the knowledge graph for **only 2 nodes (or entities)** using `pyvis`:

```
from pyvis.network import Network
from IPython.display import display

from indexing import get_graph_index_for_document

kg_index = get_graph_index_for_document(index_id="b43c9a68-7e7a-48ce-8caa-736ed9730b95", domain_name="bp")
g = kg_index.get_networkx_graph(limit=2)
net = Network(notebook=False, cdn_resources="in_line", directed=True)
net.from_nx(g)
net.show("graph.html")
```

And we received the following result:

[image]

**My Question:**

**Q1)** From where did the other nodes and edges come from?

**What did I try?**

I manually checked the contents of the graph index, and everything seems to be fine. It just stores the entities, the entity relationships, and the respective embeddings.

It seems that `pyvis` is adding something here or **Q2)** Am I missing something / doing wrong here?